# not able to fetch the attribute value from ng-bootstrap lib in angular

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Currently I'm using ng-bootstrap datepicker and trying to fetch attribute value "aria-label" from ngb-datepicker-month component but I'm not able to access the DOM directly, however I tried to use jQuery but its not fetching the value. Is there any way to fetch the attr value in ng-datepicker lib?

Typescript:

```
    ngOnInit()
      {
        $(document).ready(() => {
    
    
    console.log('arial-label: ',$('.ngb-dp-week .hidden').get('aria-label'));
        
        function formtDate(date) {
            var d = new Date(date),
            day = <any>d.getDate();

            if(<any>day.length < 2) {
              day = day;
            }
            return day;
          }
          console.log(formtDate("Moday, October 8, 2020"));
        });
  }
```

HTML:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ViewChild`. Try this:

**app.component.html**

```html
<div role="gridcell" class="ngb-dp-day hidden" aria-label="Monda, August 31, 2020" #ariaLabel></div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})

export class AppComponent {

  // Getting the reference
  @ViewChild(ariaLabel, { static: false }) div: ElementRef;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     console.log( this.div.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ng-hobby, But i have more than 20 aria-label on the page. How do i target specific one?

Comment: As you can see there is a templateReference ` #ariaLabel` on the specific div

Comment: I agree that but in my situation is somewhat different since the HTML is not accessible and its populating from ng-bootstrap.

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the non-editable component attribute

Comment: Yes, but you can put your component on a container div and use `ViewChildren` instead of `viewChild`. See this article: https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

Comment: You can use it even for dynamic HTMLs

Comment: Yes you're right @ng-hobby. its working fine now. I made spelling mistake

Comment: Great job dude ;)